# Chained equal operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I would like to add an option to make a chained comparison on objects of `MyClass`. For example:

```
MyClass one;
MyClass two;
MyClass three;
/*....*/
if (one == two == three){
    /*....*/
}
```

So that if all are equal it will return `true`, else it will return `false`.
I currently have this operator overload that works fine when comparing only two instances of `MyClass`:

```
bool operator==(const MyClass &other);
```

I understand that `one==two==three` is equal to `((one==two)==three)` so I guess that should change my `operator==` to be something like:

```
MyClass& operator==(const MyClass &other);
```

But I couldn't manage to understand how to complete this in order to be able to compare more than two instances in a row (chained).

Comment: Why not follow normal semantics and use `if (one == two && two == three)`?

Comment: Please **don't.**

Comment: @NathanOliver: indeed,  a "EqualExpr" object would have to evaluate all equalities, while normal semantics can short-circuit.

Comment: What do you mean by "make it work"?   `(one == two) == three` is not equivalent semantically to `one == two && two == three`.

Comment: Any reason ? even a tiny one?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant can you explain why not to?

Comment: 1) [Principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). Doing something in strange and unexpected ways will lead to problems with user experience/support. 2) Provide a helper function with actually helpful and self-explaining name. Edit: Answering to this comment ↓

Comment: For all that are asking why doing it. First - for practice, I think that it is possible and I don't know how, so if you know the answer I'd love to know it too. Second, wouldn't it be easier if for example I want to compare 10 different instances to check if all of them are equal?

Comment: Let's say your `MyClass` is a wrapper for a single `int`, and a solution could be given so that `x == y == z` (with `x`, `y`, and `z` of type `MyClass`) works as you want and tests if the three `int` members are equal.    Now, let's say that `a`, `b`, and `c` are equal to the `int` members of `x`, `y`, and `z` respectively.    How would you deal with the fact that `x == y == z` would produce a different result than `a == b == c`?   Which they will.

Comment: @Peter I understand that it is not the same. What do you mean by how would I deal with it? What is your point?

Comment: I'm referring to what Revolver_Ocelot is describing in terms of principle of least astonishment.   Have you ever worked with code in which two expressions that seem to have the same meaning (`x == y == z` versus `a == b == c`) actually don't?   That sort of thing makes code harder to understand, and code which is harder to understand is harder to get working.   If you don't have an idea on how you - or the user of your class - will deal with that, it's not a good idea to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, it's not good to break the usual semantics in such a way. The [Principle of least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) should be followed as mentioned.

> But I couldn't manage to understand how to complete this in order to be able to compare more than two instances in a row (chained).

Not that I think it's really a good idea to do so<sup>1</sup>, but here's a working solution:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClass {
public:
     MyClass(int x_) : x(x_), isfalse(false) {}

     const MyClass& operator==(const MyClass& rhs) const {
         if(!isfalse && x == rhs.x) {
             return rhs;
         }
         return FalseInst;
     }
     operator bool() const {
         return !isfalse;
     }
private:
     int x;
     MyClass() : x(), isfalse(true)  {}
     const bool isfalse;
     static MyClass FalseInst;
};

MyClass MyClass::FalseInst;
```

---

```
int main()
{
    MyClass one(1);
    MyClass two(1);
    MyClass three(1);

    if(one == two == three) {
        cout << "Yay!" << endl;
    }

    MyClass four(1);
    MyClass five(0);
    MyClass six(0);

    if(!(four == (five == six))) {
        cout << "Yay!" << endl;
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9a5ac5445b110be)

---

<sup>1)</sup> <sub>Note the warning issued by the compiler.</sub>

Comment: very impressive solution with minimal overhead. Although `one == (two == three)` breaks it with `three` having another value :)

Comment: now `one == two == three` breaks it with both `two` and `three` being `0`

Comment: @coyotte508 I see, it's actually not reasonably solvable.

Comment: `if(x == rhs.x)`-> `if(!isfalse && x == rhs.x)` -- sorry, I got a bit obsessed by your answer and the `static` member which impressed me :)

Answer (score 3):

As a *purely theoretical problem*, here is a way to solve it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int x;

    A(int x = 0) : x(x) {}

    struct Cmp {
        const A *ptr;
        mutable bool val;

        operator bool() const {
            return val;
        }

        const Cmp &operator == (const A &other) const {
            return other == *this;
        }
    };

    bool isEqualTo (const A &other) const {
        return x == other.x;
    }

    Cmp operator == (const A &other) const {        
        return {this, isEqualTo(other)};
    }

    const Cmp &operator == (const Cmp &other) const {
        //other.val = other.val && (*this == *other.ptr).val;
        other.val &= other.ptr->isEqualTo(*this);
        return other;
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << (A(10) == A(10) == A(10)) << endl;
    cout << (A(10) == A(9) == A(10)) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```